# Yii Url Rewrites

Tags: url-rewriting, yii

I got static pages to rewrite by modifying the urlManager like this.. `'login'=>'user/login'`

which allows `www.site.com/user/login.php` to display as `www.site.com/login.php`

The goal is to be able to take `user/` out of everything under the user directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Allright to fill in the blanks here...a solution

```
'<_a:(login|index|update|etc)>' => 'user/<_a>',
```